# Prove that $X$ is a complete metric space if every closed ball in $X$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space.

Let $x_n \in X$ be a **Cauchy** sequence.

**Proposition 1**
$$(x_n) \text{ Cauchy} \Longrightarrow (x_n) \text{ Bounded}$$

**Proposition 2**
$$(x_n) \text{ Bounded} \Longrightarrow \exists M>0: \forall n,o\in \mathbb{N},\; d(x_n,x_o)\leq M$$

Therefore $x_n\in\bar{B}(x_o,M).
$

**Proposition 3**
$$\bar{B}(x_o,M) \text{ Compact} \Longrightarrow \exists x_{n_k} \to a\in \bar{B}(x_o,M)\subset X$$
Where $x_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Proposition 4**
$$(x_n) \text{ Cauchy} \wedge (x_{n_k}) \text{ Convergent} \Longrightarrow (x_n) \text{ Convergent}$$

Therefore $(X,d)$ is complete.

Somehow I feel this is too good to be true, and I do not feel confident about my proof. Any comments, corrections, or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But its true ! Seems perfect to me ! :P

Comment: Yes, this looks good to me! If you're making a distinction between compactness and sequential compactness it might be worth adding in proposition 3 that the closed ball is sequentially compact since this is a metric space.

Comment: As an insight, every closed ball being compact is actually a very strong condition on the metric. There are plenty of complete metric spaces where it is false. For example, if you define $d$ on $\Bbb R^n$ by $d(x,y) = \min\{\|x-y\|,1\}$, then $d$ is equivalent to the canonical metric - and so is complete - but every ball of radius $> 1$ is not compact. With this strong condition on your metric, it is not surprising you found a simple straight-forward proof.